# How to write a getworldposition function in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

How to write a getworldposition function in Three.js that returns a vector?

That's my code to get the World Position of **obj** stored in vector **vec**.

```
obj.updateMatrixWorld();
var vec= new THREE.Vector3();
vec.setFromMatrixPosition(obj.matrixWorld);
```

Now I want use this three lines as a function to use it like:

```
var vector = getWorldPosition(obj);
```

Is this the right way to do it?

```
function getWorldPosition(obj)
{
    obj.updateMatrixWorld();
    var vec= new THREE.Vector3();
    vec.setFromMatrixPosition(obj.matrixWorld);
    return {vec.x, vec.y, vec.z}; // Like this?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking out how Jerome Etienne did his ObjCoord library to get an idea:

https://github.com/jeromeetienne/threex.objcoord

It's a bit outdated however:

```
/**
 * get the world position
 * @return {THREE.Vector3}  the world position
 */
THREEx.ObjCoord.worldPosition = function(object3d){
  object3d.updateMatrixWorld();
  var worldMatrix = object3d.matrixWorld;
  var worldPos  = new THREE.Vector3().getPositionFromMatrix(worldMatrix);
  return worldPos;
}
```

Your method of using the vector directly is the correct way with the latest THREE version.

Answer (score 4):

now you can use Object3D().getWorldPosition ( target ) to get the world position

target — the result will be copied into this Vector3. 
Returns a vector representing the position of the object in world space.

example:

`const anyMesh = new THREE.Mesh(g,m)
let handVec = new THREE.Vector3()
anyMesh.getWorldPosition(handVec)`

so the handVec is world position of anyMesh

more detail you can check the doc: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Object3D

Comment: looks like a backward step in usability

Comment: its good for performance, because you can reuse the same Vector3, and dont have to make a new one everytime you want to get the world position